# Loop through column names using CASE statements

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL code:

```
Declare @TestOne NVARCHAR(80) 
Set @TestOne = 'olg.FIRST_NAME' 


Select transaction_id,first_name, LAST_NAME, joint_first_name, 
joint_last_name, honoree_first_name, honoree_last_name,

    CASE WHEN olg.FIRST_NAME LIKE '% and %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END+ 
    CASE WHEN olg.FIRST_NAME LIKE '% & %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END+
    CASE WHEN olg.FIRST_NAME LIKE '% '' %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END+
    CASE WHEN olg.FIRST_NAME LIKE '% , %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END+ 
    CASE WHEN olg.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%. %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END+
    CASE WHEN olg.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%Inc%' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END+
    CASE WHEN olg.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%foundation%' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END+
    CASE WHEN olg.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%Trust%' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
    AS CKLName
from [dbo].OnlineGivingDailyLoad as olg
```

What, I want to do is use a Variable that holds the name of the other 8 columns that, I want to check for any of the characters in the above CASE statement. What, I don't want is to have to repeat the above CASE statement eight (8) time with the name of the other columns that have to be checked for these 'Strings' Is there a way like in C++ where you have a counter that loops through x amount of times and at the same time changes an array of strings (the column names) to check for the substrings in the above case statement? The variable above does not produce results when it is used in place of the column name.

Answer (score 0):

If you can stand having these on separate row instead of in separate columns you can use `apply`:

```
select colname,
       (CASE WHEN col LIKE '% and %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END + 
        CASE WHEN col LIKE '% & %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END +
        CASE WHEN col LIKE '% '' %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END +
        CASE WHEN col LIKE '% , %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END + 
        CASE WHEN col LIKE '%. %' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END +
        CASE WHEN col LIKE '%Inc%' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END +
        CASE WHEN col LIKE '%foundation%' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END +
        CASE WHEN col LIKE '%Trust%' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
       ) as colcheck
from [dbo].OnlineGivingDailyLoad olg cross apply
     (values ('first_name', olg.first_name),
             ('last_name', olg.last_name),
             . . .
     ) v(colname, col);
```

You can `pivot` or use conditional aggregation to get the values back on one row, if that is what you really want.